# How can I check to see if today is a holiday with Solspace calendar?

Tags: date, solspace-calendar

I've used Solspace Calendar to create an "Office Holidays" calendar where we enter all of the dates/times we're closed for the holidays. The idea is to let visitors know if we're open for calls or not. That said, I'm not sure what the best way is to check and see if the current time/date lands on a holiday or not. Especially without looping through all holidays in the calendar.

Any suggestions on ways to check to see if we're currently in a "holiday"?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't you only have to loop through the events on a specific day (today) to see if there is a match for a holiday (and not the entire calendar)?  I believe you could use the "[Day](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/day/#parameters)" loop with a date_range_start of current_time, couldn't you?  And since your calendar entries are limited to office holidays, the return of any results for a given day would in fact mean there is a holiday.

So something like:

```
 {exp:calendar:day date_range_start="{current_time format="%Y-%m-%d"}"}
    {if calendar_no_results}
       Regular business hours today
    {/if}
       Today is a Holiday!
 {/exp:calendar:day}
```

Comment: That's right. I don't want all holidays, just holidays for today's date, and even limited to 1 since even one means there is a company holiday.

Comment: Not sure `{exp:calendar:day}` is a good method, though, because it outputs template code that I don't need.

Answer (score 3):

Creating an "Office Holidays" calendar is a good start. Within that calendar you would create your holiday "events" in the "Calendar: Events" channel.

If you're looking to list the upcoming holidays as a list, you can use `{exp:calendar:cal}`. Don't forget to use `calendar_id=""` or `calendar_name=""` is you just want to display events within your "Office Holidays" calendar:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
  calendar_id="1"
  date_range_start="today"
  date_range_end="+6 months"
  pad_short_weeks="n"}

  {events}
     Holiday "{event_title}" on {event_start_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}<br />
  {/events}

{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

You can also create a calendar table using `{exp:calendar:cal}` (see the [advanced example for a monthly calendar here](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/month//#examples)), then use

```
 {if day_event_total > 0}Holiday!{/if}
```

...within the `{display_each_day}{/display_each_day}` tag pair to label days with holidays. Make sure the `{events}{/events}` tag pair is also present in the `{display_each_day}{/display_each_day}` tag pair.